# How multiple import files into React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have a question about multiple imports in React.

i have a structure like that eg:

- src

  - validations

    - required

      - index.js
    - number

      - index.js

and i basically import these files to my React component with this way and everything works well

```
import {required} from "validations/required";
import {number} from "validations/number";
```

but when these imports is to much my file is getting so much line of code and looks ugly.

so i tried to make it like that:

```
   import {required, number} from "validations";
```

and like that:

```
import {required, number} from "validations/";
```

booth solutions not worked. 
It's giving to me error:

```
Module not found: Can't resolve 'validations/' in '/Users/...../Components/MyComponent'
```

i didn't understand why but seems like react search that files in my `MyComponent` folder.

how can handle it ?

Comment: create index file in validation folder. import all files simply export them.

Comment: how? creating index.js file to validations folder and import all files to there and export them  ?  how export them multiply ?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-tesla-mjy4p

Comment: i understood thank you :)